# Clojure :why does this macro do not work?

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm exploring macros with basic examples and I do not understand how it works.

This :

```
(defmacro evalf [f v]
  (f v))
(evalf + 2)
```

does not work.

I tried :

```
(defmacro evalf [f v]
  '(f v))
(evalf + 2)
```

no luck...

I do not understand other syntaxes : ~ ~@ and so on but they does not work either. I see that symbol f is not pointing on + but I do not know to say "take the value of f which is +".

Can you make it clearer ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what do you want to do there are two variants:

First one (the one you probably want) is:

```
(defmacro evalf [f v] `(~f ~v))
```

or

```
(defmacro evalf [f v] (list f v))
```

Both of them do the same thing: generate the s-expression you need.
With this one `(evalf + 10)` would be expanded to `(+ 10)` in compile-time, and then successfully evaluated in runtime.

Second one is this:

```
(defmacro evalf [f v] ((resolve f) v))
```

Now the function `f` would be **called** at compile-time, so macro would be expanded to the result: `10`

Your variant with `(f v)` failed silently, because when you call `(evalf + 10)`,
the `+` here is just a plain symbol, not a reference to the function from macro's point of view, so it tries to call `('+ 10)`, since the symbol in clojure has function's semantics, it is totally correct syntax, but this call produces `nil`. (the example of symbol call: `('+ {'+ 10})` => 10) So if you want to get the function, named as this symbol, you will have to resolve it, as in my second example.

And the variant with `'(f v)` just expands to the list of two symbols : `'f` and `'v`, and then leads to the runtime call `('f 'v)` that also returns `nil`, like the first variant.

Comment: Thanks, both are answers but I understood more yours so I chose this

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
(defmacro evalf [f v]
  (list f v))

(evalf (partial * 2) 66); 132
```

In the call of `evalf`

- the arguments pass unevaluated as *forms* `(partial * 2)` and `66`;
- the body of the macro yields the *expression* `(list '(partial * 2) '66)`;

  - which evaluates to the form `((partial * 2) 66)`
  - which, returned from the macro, evaluates to `132`.

An alternative, using syntax quoting, is

```
(defmacro evalf [f v]
  `(~f ~v))
```